# lld-link: error: undefined symbol: _mm_set_ps

Tags: clang, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to use SIMD intrinsics on Clang compiler for Windows and I'm getting undefined symbol error. What am I missing? There is no such a library for intrinsics, the compiler should just know how to put them into the code.

I'm also getting this erro with the MSVC linker.

Just a example code.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

extern inline float
pmath_Sinf(float radians)
{
  __m128 radians_ps = _mm_set_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, radians);

  return 0.0f;
}

extern inline float
pmath_Cosf(float radians)
{
  __m128 radians_ps = _mm_set_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, radians);

  return 0.0f;
}
```

These are the command line output with verbosity.

```
clang version 12.0.0
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.28.29333 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -main-file-name windows_main.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -relaxed-aliasing -menable-no-infs -menable-no-nans -menable-unsafe-fp-math -fno-signed-zeros -mreassociate -freciprocal-math -fno-trapping-math -ffp-contract=fast -fno-rounding-math -ffp-exception-behavior=ignore -ffast-math -ffinite-math-only -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -mllvm -x86-asm-syntax=intel -tune-cpu generic -D_MT -flto-visibility-public-std -D_VC_NODEFAULTLIB -fno-rtti-data -fms-volatile -fdiagnostics-format msvc -gno-column-info -gcodeview -debug-info-kind=limited -v -nobuiltininc -resource-dir "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0" -D DEVELOPMENT -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\atlmfc\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\ucrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.19041.0\\shared" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.19041.0\\um" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" -O0 -Weverything -Werror -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-missing-variable-declarations -Wno-cast-align -Wno-language-extension-token -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=unused-variable --std=c99 -fdebug-compilation-dir "C:\\Users\\Leonardo\\Desktop\\Projects\\Primal Library\\src\\windows" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length=120 -mstack-probe-size=9999999 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.28.29333 -fdelayed-template-parsing -finline-hint-functions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o "C:\\Users\\Leonardo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\windows_main-c555fe.obj" -x c windows_main.c
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 based upon LLVM 12.0.0-6923b0a7 default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\atlmfc\include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt
End of search list.
In file included from windows_main.c:8:
./../math.c(17,10): warning: unused variable 'radians_ps' [-Wunused-variable]
  __m128 radians_ps = _mm_set_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, radians);
         ^
./../math.c(27,10): warning: unused variable 'radians_ps' [-Wunused-variable]
  __m128 radians_ps = _mm_set_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, radians);
         ^
windows_main.c(174,14): warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
             ^
windows_main.c(174,26): warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
                         ^
4 warnings generated.
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\lld-link" "-out:..\\..\\build\\windows_development_x64\\primal.exe" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\atlmfc\\lib\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.19041.0\\um\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\12.0.0\\lib\\windows" -nologo -debug /INCREMENTAL:NO /NODEFAULTLIB /OPT:REF /STACK:0x100000,0x100000 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /WX "C:\\Users\\Leonardo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\windows_main-c555fe.obj" kernel32.lib
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: _mm_set_ps
>>> referenced by C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\Projects\Primal Library\src\math.c:17
>>>               C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp\windows_main-c555fe.obj:(pmath_Sinf)
>>> referenced by C:\Users\Leonardo\Desktop\Projects\Primal Library\src\math.c:27
>>>               C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Local\Temp\windows_main-c555fe.obj:(pmath_Cosf)
clang-cl: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you remember to `#include <xmmintrin.h>`?  Do you get any warnings about implicit declarations?

Comment: @NateEldredge sure. Compilation went well. Only linkage isn't working.

Comment: If the compiler output a `_mm_set_ps` symbol, then compilation did not go well.  That's not a normal function, and there is no `_mm_set_ps` symbol; the compiler shouldn't be calling a symbol.  Please make sure you included the header, and if that doesn't do the trick post some example code.

Comment: @nemequ I did include the header. If not I would receive a "implicit declaration of function '_mm_set_ps' is invalid in C99" error. I'm receiving a linker error. Linking comes AFTER compilation. I wouldn't even get a linker error if the header file was not included. Isn't that obvious??

Comment: No, it's not at all obvious. C89 [is happy to let you use functions which haven't been declared](https://godbolt.org/z/cs85sE), and if the function doesn't exist in the ABI (like, for example, `_mm_set_ps`) you'll end up with a linker error exactly as you described. Since you didn't provide much information in your initial post (such as which C standard, or even if this was C or C++) a missing header is a *very* reasonable thing to look for first.

Comment: To be clear: if you're getting an error from the linker about `_mm_set_ps` being undefined, compilation obviously went wrong because there should be no references to `_mm_set_ps`; it isn't a normal function, it's an intrinsic.  There is no `_mm_set_ps` function in the ABI for the linker to link to.

What you have is not a linker error, it's a compilation error which is only manifesting at link time.  I can't reproduce the problem, so I can't be sure what is going wrong. but if you post the commands you're using to compile and link so people can reproduce the problem we might be able to help.

Comment: Sounds like your `xmmintrin.h` is broken.  If this was a 32-bit build, are you sure you enabled SSE?  Like `-march=native` or `-march=nehalem` or whatever?  `-msse` might not be on by default with `-m32`.  Possibly try `immintrin.h`, in case that helps for some reason.  xmmintrin.h should work for an SSE1 intrinsic like that, but IDK.

Comment: @PeterCordes `immintrin.h` didn't work. I edited my question and now I provided all the command line arguments by using `-v` verbose. See if that is something I'm missing. PS.: Yes, I'm using `/NODEFAULTLIB` to not link with any standard library, but I already managed to use SIMD that way before.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think immintrin.h would help, but you don't appear to have even tried my other suggestion.  I don't see a `-march=` or a `-msse` on your command line; only 64-bit make SSE2 baseline. `_mm_set_ps` is a "synthetic" intrinsic, not for any specific machine instruction, perhaps it's not erroring like `_mm_add_ps` would about trying to inline a builtin not supported by the target?  And BTW, nothing about linking makes any difference, `/NODEFAULTLIB` should be fine.  As nemequ already told you, the fact that it compiles to a function-call instead of inlining is already the problem.

Comment: Although I guess this is a 64-bit build, given the `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.28.29333`?  That would rule out a missing `-msse`.  Is your clang install using MSVC's xmmintrin.h because of `-I` or `-internal-isystem` options?  If so, maybe it needs GCC's version of that header, or its own.  (IDK the details of what clang needs, but I could imagine an MSVC version ending up just declaring a prototype without an implementation when clang compiles it.)

Comment: Hey everyone, I got it! @PeterCordes were right, that was something wrong with my `xmmintrin.h` header file and I know what. I have both Clang and MSVC installed. Both of them comes with its own `xmmintrin.h` header file, since it is compiler specific. So, I realized that with `#include <xmmintrin.h>`, Clang was including the MSVC version, probably bacause it was first in the PATH. All I did was to specify `/X` to stop searching for include paths and created a new `xmmintrin.h` by copying and pasting the things I need from the Clang `xmmintrin.h` into it.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, instead of just a comment.

Comment: Yes I will. Thank you everyone for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.

Since I have both Clang and MSVC installed, both of them has its own `xmmintrin.h` header file in their include path, since it is compiler specific. I realized that with `#include <xmmintrin.h>`, Clang was including the MSVC version, probably because it found first in the PATH. So all I did was use `/X` compiler option that makes it stoping searching for include paths, and I created a new `xmmintrin.h` file by coping and pasting all I needed from the actual Clang `xmmintrin.h` into it.

Thanks everyone for your comments.